# Spree replace default Image / noimage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

I am working on a Rails project which involves Spree 1.3.2 and I need to change the default image (noimage) in Spree, but so far found no way to do it. I searched through the documentation, went through the admin section, but all failed.

I have been overriding the default layouts for Spree with Slim templates by following the same name. I located the noimage in `app\assets\images\noimage\` folder in the source. So I created the path and copied my custom images there. But the image link still shows the old ugly spree default image.

How can this be accomplished? I do not like to edit core files, something like an override would be great.

Comment: The answer worked for me - is there anything stopping you accepting it?

Answer (score 20):

To override the no-image placeholder of spree. 
Create the following folder in your rails project

```
app/assets/images/noimage
```

Create the following image files with the png file extension. The name and file extension is crucial here otherwise you wouldn't override spree's default version

- large.png
- mini.png
- product.png
- small.png

Make sure you matched the resolution of the spree's default images when you are creating the no-image assets.

```
large(240x240)
mini(48x48)
product(240x240)
small(100x100)
```